# TypeError: find is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

> Not able to  to figure out why its "find is not a function" I am new
> at Nodejs and Mongodb. want to show database document using ejs Please help me out. I checked connection to DB, it's ok. I also read some other questions but any suitable answer for my problem. It showing
> **TypeError: clgModel.find is not a function**

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
    var clgModel = require('../modules/engg_clg');
    var router = express.Router();
    var college = clgModel.find({});
    
    
    /* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      college.exec(function(err, data) {
    
        if (err) throw err;
        res.render('index', {
          title: 'Engineering College Rank',
          records: data
        });
      });
    
    });
    
    module.exports = router;

**
```

**engg.js**

**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Engg_clg_rnk', {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});
var conn = mongoose.connection;

var collegeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  id: Number,
  City: String,
  Institute_ID: String,
  Name: String,
  Rank: Number,
  Score: Number,
  State: String`enter code here`

});


var collegeModel = mongoose.model('Employee', collegeSchema);
module.export = collegeModel;
```

> **`EJS`**
>
> > showing the database document in tabular form

```
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">City</th>
      <th scope="col">Institute_ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Rank</th>
      <th scope="col">Score</th>
      <th scope="col">State</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <% records.forEach(function(row){%>
  <tr>

    <td><%= row.City %></td>
    <td><%= row.Institute_ID %></td>
    <td><%= row.Name %></td>
    <td><%= row.Rank %></td>
    <td><%= row.Score %></td>
    <td><%= row.State %></td>



  </tr>

  <% }) %>
</table>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

you have to import that from object like

```
const { collegeModel } = require("../models/recipe.model");
```

Or

```
   const clgModel = require('../modules/engg_clg');

   const college = clgModel.collegeModel.find({});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```js
module.export = collegeModel;
```

in your `engg.js` so it is a type error just put an 's' and write it:

```js
module.exports = collegeModel;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 file. `collegeModel.js` and `index.js`

1. paste this code in `collegeModel.js`

```js
var mongoose = require("mongoose")

const collegeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: {
    type: Number
  },
  City: {
    type: String
  },
  Institute_ID: {
    type: String
  },
  Name: {
    type: String
  },
  Rank: {
    type: Number
  },
  Score: {
    type: Number
  },
  State: {
    type: String
  }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Employee", collegeSchema)
```

2. Add this code in `index.js`

```js
const collegeModel = require("./collegeModel.js")

router.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {

  const result = await collegeModel.find().lean()

  if (result) {
    res.render('index', {
      title: 'Engineering College Rank',
      records: data
    });

  } else {
    console.log("ERROR")
  }

});
```