# Mongoose Schema cannot be identified by code

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
//broken schema
var coursesSchema = new Schema({
    college: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    units: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    course_code: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    course_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    class_number: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    section: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    class_day: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    time_start: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    time_end: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    faculty: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Courses', coursesSchema);
```

---

```
//working schema
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var loaSchema = new Schema({
    process_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
   process_details: {
       type: String,
       required: true
    },
    process_deadline: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('LOA', loaSchema);
```

I have this schema which I export into `index.js` file. This schema works in other parts of the code except in index.js. When I query Courses schema, it returns `model.find()` is not a function. When I try creating a new Courses object it says `Constructor is not a schema`. I have other schemas that work fine inside `index.js` and I get to query them, but this schema is an exception.

Does anyone know the reason behind this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40280783/mongoose-typeerror-schema-is-not-a-constructor

I get the same error as this person ^^^^ I've tried all solutions in that question but to no avail

Comment: which mongodb and mongoose version are you using?

Comment: "mongoose": "^6.2.10"
"connect-mongo": "^4.4.1"

Comment: TypeError: model.find is not a function 
still the same error ;-;

Comment: can you tell me how you imported the model in your index.js, i guess i got the error just need to check?

Comment: `const Course = ('./models/coursesModel.js');`

Answer (score 1):

index.js is the special file and actually it's root of your module, it's better separate the schema from that to prevent from bugs

Comment: i've just finished separating the files and the error still stays the same

Comment: give it model to variable  like const loa = mongoose.model('LOA', loaSchema); exports.loa = loa

Comment: ` TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined ` it gives me this error

Comment: how you import that ?

Comment: const Courses = ('./models/coursesModel.js'); and then when i call the function i write it as univbotdb.findMany(Courses.courses, {"college":ticketDetails.student_college}).then(resultArray => { console.log(resultArray); }

Comment: just to clarify again: the broken schema is Courses btw, not loa

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71900860/13302494 check this one

Comment: I used both import solutions and I got this error for the first  TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined 

and this for the second TypeError: Cannot read property 'findMany' of undefined